# Possible to use Akavanche with Azure Mobile Apps?

Tags: azure, sqlite, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I seem to have 3 different installs of SQLLite and want to see if I can consolidate them, or if that is even a good idea to do so.  (or if there are conflicts).

Below I have

1. Akavanche.sqlite3
2. Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore
3. Some SQLite raw references.

I'm not sure where some of these came from (aside from Akavanche and Azure), but I want to save space within my app. (Apple App Store is 100MB)

What should I do with all these references, is it OK?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For each library, you need the dependency tree.

[Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore/) depends on:

- SQLitePCLRaw.core
- SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green

This latter has a huge list of platform-specific dependencies, some of which you see in your list.  Akavache has a dependency on a different SQLite database edition (the e_sqlite3 version).  So, I think you need all of the SQLite libraries because of the differing dependencies.